# Adjust spatial autocorrelation in multilevel logistic regression using autocovariate in R

Tags: autocorrelation, multilevel-analysis, spatial

In the large volume of cluster data (i.e. `300K` individuals are nested within `800` districts) with a binomial outcome variable (disease/non-disease), I'm using two-level logistic regression to assess the association between the predictor and outcome adjusting for cluster (i.e. district) effects using (`glmer` function from `lme4` package in R). The variance of random effects (district) is high (about `1.71`). Besides, I've extracted district-specific residuals and tried to find the Moran's I (about `0.250`, `p<0.001`). It looks there is a substantial spatial autocorrelation in residuals, and I suspect this spatial autocorrelation will impact inferential results. How can I adjust this spatial autocorrelation in a simple way forlarge data? Is there any R package available to treat this smoothly? Would it be possible to solve this problem by creating a residual based autocovariate and adjusting this variable in the model as a covariate?